# Confusion regarding duplicates in a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a Pandas dataframe , for which I am checking for duplicates. I get the following output, but I dont know why its showing them as duplicates. Isnt all the column values in a row supposed to be same to be shown as a duplicate? Please correct me if I am wrong, I am newbie in Python

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to _do_ in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per default, [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) does not count the first occurence of a duplicated row.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1], [2,2], [1,1], [1,1]])
>>> df
   0  1
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  1  1
3  1  1
>>> df.duplicated()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

This means that your `df[dup]` will have unique rows if the duplicate rows in `df` were only duplicated twice.

You can adjust this behavior with the `keep` argument.

```
>>> df.duplicated(keep=False)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```